# ASP.NET Multiple Validation Controls on a single asp.net input control?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have the following textbox alongwith its validators, but when I enter the correct text it fires up the RegularExpressionValidator error message, can't really figure out what I am doing wrong

```
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" onkeypress="return keyRestrict(event,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-0123456789')"
                AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Width="199px"></asp:TextBox><span style="color: Red">*</span>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="txtName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"
                CssClass="text-error" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^[\p{L}\s]+$" ErrorMessage="Invalid Name"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I also used the ValidationExpression `^[A-Za-z]+$` in order to test that whether there exist some error in the ValidationExpression, and then typed in `Name` in the textbox being validated and still it triggered the error message of the RegularExpressionValidator.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^[\p{L}\s]+$` would match 1 or more letters only(not digits) or space..

If you want to validate it with digits you have to use

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}\s]+$
```

This would match unicode letters,numbers and space 1 to many times

Comment: Actually I want it to accept the letters only, and no digits and special characters

Comment: @MuhammadMamoorKhan the first regex does what you want

Comment: no it doesn't, it only accepts any number of the character p, and I don't know why

Comment: yes it works, I just found out that there was some stinking typo mistake I'm extremely sorry, thank you very much dear